# kiiling a request on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat

I have Tomcat 7 on Windows, and in the status page: http:///manager/status I see many requests that are probably stuck. I tried to stop and start the application that generated them, but they survived. Is it possible to kill these processes, without restarting Tomcat entirely?